# Как поместить несколько списков в один? Python

Tags: python, sql, list

Всем привет. Есть около 600 списков, каждый из которых выглядит примерно так:
[1, thebestnick, user, 150, one]

Соответственно, выводятся они вот так:

```
[1, thebestnick, user, 150, one]
[2, kotyara, user, 300, five]
[3, granato, user, 100, one]
[4, mickv, superuser, 500, two]
[5, monkey, user, 80, four]
```

А нужно вывести одним списком. Примерно вот так:

```
[
1, thebestnick, user, 150, one
2, kotyara, user, 300, five
3, granato, user, 100, one
4, mickv, superuser, 500, two
5, monkey, user, 80, four
]
```

Как это сделать? Мне это нужно для отправки в MySQL. Так как если создать цикл на отправку в таблицу, то по одному все 600 списков переносятся около 3 минут, хотя парсятся всего за полсекунды. Поэтому нужен один список, чтобы отправлять разом

Comment: отправляйте список списков [[], [], [] ...]

Comment: spisok = [send_py,]

        print(spisok)

Comment: сделал так. Всё равно выводит каждый по-одному

Comment: у вас в желаемом результате не один список, а вообще не пойми что. как разделяется "one" и 2?

Comment: а что такое send_py?

Comment: в эту переменную отправляются значения из цикла. То есть send_py = (num, nick, userstatus, value, place) print(send_py) >>> [1, thebestnick, user, 150, one]

Comment: перед циклом: ```my_list = []```
внутри цикла: ```my_list.append(send_py)```
и тогда будет список со списками

Comment: Выдал None равное числу списков